# API call / state in an EventHandler is always one step behind - cant fix it with an useEffect

Tags: reactjs, rest, asynchronous, react-hooks

So basically I try to get data (movie list) from an API call when clicking on a NavLink, but the state or the param is always one step behind.

I think the problem is that the handler is async. But I can't find the solution to make it work. For example, I tried to get the id of movie list with event.target, but then when copying a route for example genre/99-Documentary and opening it in a new tap it would render /.

Could somebody help me? Would really appreciate it.

```
export default function DiscoverMovies(props) {
  const { setMovies } = props;
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  const params = useParams();
  let genreId = params.id;

  async function handleGetMovieList(event) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&with_genres=${genreId}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setMovies(data.results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${apiKey}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setGenres(data.genres);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [setGenres]);

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="genre-list">
        {genres.map((genre) => (
          <li className="genre-list__item" key={genre.id}>
            <NavLink
              exact
              id={genre.id}
              onClick={handleGetMovieList}
              activeClassName="active"
              to={`/genre/${genre.id}-${genre.name}`}
            >
              {genre.name}
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `onClick`, define a `useEffect` that's sensitive to `genreId`:

```js
export default function DiscoverMovies({ setMovies }) {
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const first = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (first.current) {
      first.current = false;
      return;
    }

    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&with_genres=${id}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovies(data.results);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [setMovies, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${apiKey}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setGenres(data.genres);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul className="genre-list">
      {genres.map((genre) => (
        <li className="genre-list__item" key={genre.id}>
          <NavLink
            exact
            id={genre.id}
            activeClassName="active"
            to={`/genre/${genre.id}-${genre.name}`}
          >
            {genre.name}
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

`first` is used to prevent `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie` from being fetched on the initial render.